QLThumbnailGenerationRequest not generating thumbnail from the image captured from camera
I am facing an issue with QLThumbnailGenerationRequest, it is not creating thumbnail from the image captured from the iPhone camera. I am doing the following:

I get the captured image and convert it into NSData like this:

UIImage *source = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(source, 1.0);


Then I save the imageData to a temporary directory like this:

NSString *directoryPath = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CapturedImageFromCamera.jpg"];
    
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = [imageData writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

I am getting success as true which means that the image is saved at the given path.

I am creating QLThumbnailGenerationRequest like this:

CGSize thumbnailSize = CGSizeMake(720, 720);
QLThumbnailGenerator *generator = [[QLThumbnailGenerator alloc] init];
QLThumbnailGenerationRequest *request = [[QLThumbnailGenerationRequest alloc] initWithFileAtURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] size:thumbnailSize scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale representationTypes:QLThumbnailGenerationRequestRepresentationTypeThumbnail];

    [generator generateBestRepresentationForRequest:request completionHandler:^(QLThumbnailRepresentation * _Nullable thumbnail, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR = %@", error.localizedDescription);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
        }
        
    }];

I am getting the following error everytime:
Thumbnail generation failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (QLThumbnailErrorDomain error 0.)
Error code: 0
Error domain: QLThumbnailErrorDomain
Error user info: {
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=QLThumbnailErrorDomain Code=102 \"(null)\"";

Let me know if you need any further details reagarding this issue.
Any help regarding this would be appreciated. Thanks

Did you try on real device ?

Yes I tried on a real device and I am getting this error everytime. I have a sample app created if you want to try it.

I'd love to try it

From here you download the sample project.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HRJ9Cdnj4vymbZojpU9OI-80L2mGuQ1s/view?usp=sharing
You need to try it on your device. Once you run it you will see a button. When you tap on it, it will show you an action sheet with two options (Camera/Library) you need to select Camera and the rest is given in the question. I'll be waiting to hear from you soon.

I tried it. It's just like you wrote, but I don't get the error, I took a photo then selected the photo and got “success” in the log (Without any changes in code, just change deployment target to 16.6)
Maybe the problem is in the read accesses from the specified directory ?
System Info:
iOS 17.6.1
Developer mode on

Can you try using the latest iOS 18?

I tried on iOS 18 works without problem
